# Amnesia strange screen shaking

Tags: monitor, amnesia-the-dark-descent

I'm making a custom story (sorry if this should be on the GameDev), but when I enter the map and it fades in, the screen shakes (rolls) (counter)clockwise.
Here's a video:

My start area is 1 * 1 * 1 and is placed at 0 Y. I'm not sure if it's right.

Thanks for advice.